# Find multiple of 3 or 5 using Ruby

Tags: ruby

This code produces the following answer: 234168

```
total = 0
0.upto(1000).each do |i|
  total += i if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
end

puts total
```

Project Euler says my answer is incorrect. Am I doing something wrong with Ruby? Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected answer?

Comment: @edgerunner: Project euler doesn't give answer. This is for question #1 by the way.

Comment: I mean do you expect an array or a sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-read the question:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3
>   or 5 *below* 1000.